# Black ops 3 campaign: How is the score calculated?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3

So I have been trying to complete all the accolades for the black ops 3 campaign missions and couldn't see an obvious way the score is calculated at the end (each mission has a score based accolade).  I have tried looking around online and haven't found anything.

Has anyone found anything detailing how the scores are calculated in campaign mode? (I.E., are headshots worth more than regular kills?  Do deaths count against you? etc.)

Answer (score 1):

So I found the paragraph below from the website Steam. It was the only one I could find about the scoring system after searching for about 2 hours. It was copied and pasted straight from that website so its not in my own words. Hope this helps..unless you found it or figured it out already haha!

The score system has been greatly simplified since Black Ops 2. There is now no difficulty bonus, nor any bonus for having all accolades. Mostly, the system is simply 100 points for a human kill, 150 for a robot and a custom amount for other enemy types. That's it. Unlike Combat Immersion where there are bonuses, achieving the required score is simply about killing as many enemies as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer (yea, still here 2 years later, although not really playing COD anymore).  I will accept this answer if you can add the actual link to Steam website where you found this, (not trying to be difficult, honest).  Thanks again!